# Format output of xargs

Tags: xargs

I would like to change the format of the output xargs displays

```
cat k.txt 
1 
2 
3
```

And

```
cat k.txt | xargs 
1 2 3
```

However I would like to have `1, 2, 3` or `1|2|3`. Any suggestions?

Comment: That could be achieved with something (not exactly this) like `xargs cat -n`, but is easier if you just trim the newline characters, this can be achieved with `echo $(cat)`, `grep` or `awk` (crawl the way to do it). `xargs` don't fit well for your current purpose.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Below are a dozen or so examples of how you can take a file such as this:

```
$ cat k.txt
1
2
3
```

and convert it to this format:

```
1,2,3
```

You can use this command to create the above file if you'd like to play along:

```
$ cat <<EOF > k.txt
1
2
3
EOF
```

The examples below are split into 2 groups. Ones that "work" and ones that "almost" work. I leave these because often times it's just as valuable to see why something doesn't work, as it is to see why something does.

Most scripting languages that I'm familiar with are represented. Some are represented multiple times, since as with the famous acronym typically referenced in Perl, [TIMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it).

**NOTE:** You can swap out the comma (`,`) in the examples below and replace it with whatever characters you want, i.e. `|`.

#### Examples that "work"

These code snippets will produce the desired output.

*The `paste` command:*

```
$ paste -s -d ',' k.txt 
1,2,3
```

*The `sed` command:*

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' k.txt
1,2,3

$ sed ':a;{N;s/\n/,/};ba' k.txt 
1,2,3
```

*The `perl` command:*

```
$ perl -00 -p -e 's/\n(?!$)/,/g' k.txt
1,2,3

$ perl -00 -p -e 'chomp;tr/\n/,/' k.txt
1,2,3
```

*The `awk` command:*

```
$ awk '{printf"%s%s",c,$0;c=","}' k.txt
1,2,3

$ awk '{printf "%s,",$0}' k.txt | awk '{sub(/\,$/,"");print}'
1,2,3

$ awk -vORS=, 1 k.txt | awk '{sub(/\,$/,"");print}'
1,2,3

$ awk 'BEGIN {RS="dn"}{gsub("\n",",");print $0}' k.txt | awk '{sub(/\,$/,"");print}'
1,2,3
```

*The `python` command:*

```
$ python -c "import sys; print sys.stdin.read().replace('\n', ',')[0:-1]" <k.txt
1,2,3

$ python -c "import sys; print sys.stdin.read().replace('\n', ',').rstrip(',')" <k.txt
1,2,3
```

*Bash's `mapfile` built-in:*

```
$ mapfile -t a < k.txt; (IFS=','; echo "${a[*]}")
1,2,3
```

*The `ruby` command:*

```
$ ruby -00 -pe 'gsub /\n/,",";chop' < k.txt
1,2,3

$ ruby -00 -pe '$_.chomp!"\n";$_.tr!"\n",","' k.txt
1,2,3
```

*The `php` command:*

```
$ php -r 'echo strtr(chop(file_get_contents($argv[1])),"\n",",");' k.txt
1,2,3
```

***Caveats***

Most of the examples above will work just fine. Some have hidden issues, such as the PHP example above. The function `chop()` is actually an alias to `rtrim()`, so the last line's trailing spaces will also be removed.

So too do does the first Ruby example, and the first Python example. The issue is with how they're all making use of a type of operation that essentially "chops" off, blindly, a trailing character. This is fine in for the example that the OP provided, but care must be taken when using these types of one liners to make sure that they conform with the data they're processing.

***Example***

Say our sample file, `k.txt` looked like this instead:

```
$ echo -en "1\n2\n3" > k.txt
```

It looks similar but it has one slight difference. It doesn't have a trailing newline (`\n`) like the original file. Now when we run the first Python example we get this:

```
$ python -c "import sys; print sys.stdin.read().replace('\n', ',')[0:-1]" <k.txt
1,2,
```

#### Examples that "almost" work

These are the ["always a bridesmaid, never a bride"](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/always+a+bridesmaid,+never+a+bride.html) examples. Most of them could probably be adapted, but when working a potential solution to a problem, when it feels "forced", it's probably the wrong tool for the job!

*The `perl` command:*

```
$ perl -p -e 's/\n/,/' k.txt
1,2,3,
```

*The `tr` command:*

```
$ tr '\n' ','  < k.txt 
1,2,3,
```

*The `cat` + `echo` commands:*

```
$ echo $(cat k.txt)
1 2 3
```

*The `ruby` command:*

```
$ ruby -pe '$_["\n"]=","' k.txt
1,2,3,
```

*Bash's `while` + `read` built-ins:*

```
$ while read line; do echo -n "$line,"; done < k.txt
1,2,3,
```

Comment: Regarding `awk` I prefer a shorter alternative: `awk -vORS=, 1 k.txt`

Comment: Not sure whether CentOS has `bash`: `mapfile -t a < k.txt; (IFS=','; echo "${a[*]}")`

Comment: not sure about the trailing newline. According to my test your `perl` and first `awk` has them too.

Comment: I would put the `paste` one at the top. That's exactly what `paste -s` is for here. It's a standard command and would be the most efficient. All the other ones are overkill and/or  are not portable or have limitations.

Comment: `mapfile` is relatively new, added in `bash` 4.0.

Comment: For `awk` without trailing separator maybe this is nicer: `awk '{printf"%s%s",c,$0;c=","}' k.txt`

Comment: Nice! You can dodge the final newline in the perl version by setting the record seperator to slurp the whole file into one line, then use a negative lookahead in the regexp: `perl -00 -p -e 's/\n(?!$)/,/g' k.txt` yields `1,2,3`.

Comment: `ruby` without trailing separator: `ruby -00 -pe '$_.chomp!"\n";$_.tr!"\n",","' k.txt`. (The same in `perl`, to avoid regular expressions: `perl -00 -p -e 'chomp;tr/\n/,/' k.txt`)

Comment: I would not just `chop` unconditionally. If the input file has no trailing newline, your `ruby`'s output will be “1,2,”.

Comment: I think we skipped `php`: `php -r 'echo strtr(chop(file_get_contents($argv[1])),"\n",",");' k.txt` (With a note: `php`'s `chop()` is actually alias to `rtrim()`, so the last line's trailing spaces will also be removed.)

Comment: @manatwork - no we didn't 8-)

Comment: Ok, one more thing: the `[0:-1]` in the `python` code works like the `chop()` in `ruby`: removes the last character unconditionally, even if is not newline. `rstrip("\n")` only trailing newlines (and `rstrip()` removes all trailing spaces).

Comment: @manatwork - they're like rubiks cubes, can't put them down can you?

Comment: @manatwork - I'll add your suggests and fixes today/suggestions today in a bit. Give a couple of hours, I'll drop a note so you can review.

Comment: @manatwork - I moved all your examples up into the answer.

Answer (score 8):

@slm already given nice answer, but as your question "format output of xargs"

```
xargs -I{} echo -n "{}|" < test.txt
```

- `-I` is "replace strings" option.
- `{}` is a placeholder for output text.
- This is similar to the use of a curly-bracket pair in "find."

If you want to get rid of the trailing `|` you can use `sed` to do some clean up:

```
$ xargs -I{} echo -n "{}|" < k.txt  | sed -e 's/|$//'
1|2|3
```

Comment: That tacks an extra pipe on after the 3. "1|2|3|". I've been having the same issue with a while loop and awk solution.

Comment: yes, if there is new line.. `tr`,`sed` and other also..

Answer (score 3):

This is an old thread, I know. The OP asked with a simple code like this. To keep it close to the original, I have a simple solution.

```
cat k.txt | xargs
1 2 3
```

use sed

```
cat k.txt | xargs | sed 's/ /,/g'
1,2,3
```

or

```
cat k.txt | xargs | sed 's/ /|/g'
1|2|3
```

sed can look a little weird but broken down, it makes much sense.

's is for substitute. 
g' is for global : without this, it will only do the first substitution on each new line. Since you use 'xargs' it displays them as one line. So you will get "1,2 3".

The delimiter is used for separation. I used the / character. One interesting trick: you can replace the delimiter with most any other character, as long as we keep it the same format between the quotes. So this would work also....

```
cat k.txt | xargs | sed 's# #,#g'
```

or

```
cat k.txt | xargs | sed 'sT T,Tg'
```

Obviously, using certain chars as the delimiter can get confusing, so be smart.

Answer (score 0):

```
xargs <k.txt | tr \  \|
```

You don't need `cat` - just pass in the file input and - if given no other command - `xargs` will pass out its default format - which is of a kind with `/bin/echo`'s *(without backslash c-escape interpretations)*.

`xargs` will strip off head/tail whitespace from the input file and squeeze other sequences of whitespace down to a single space. This means that while passing the file from `tr` to `xargs` like:

```
tr \\n \| <k.txt | xargs
```

...prints...

```
1|2|3|
```

...going *the other way* and operating only on the *args* that `xargs` space-delimits does....

```
1|2|3\n
```

...because `xargs` prints the final trailing newline *(as is required for a text file)*, but it doesn't get `tr`anslated that way.

Note, though, that this *(or any other solution offered here)* does not account for `xargs` quoting in input. `xargs` will pass out literally single/double/backslash-quoted non-newline whitespace chars in input, which can themselves be quoted like:

```
xargs <<\IN
1    2'      3'\'      \'4
IN
```

---

```
1 2      3' '4
```