# Deleting text after a character multiple times in one column

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, bioinformatics

So I have certain text set up in the second and third columns of my file like so:

```
GO:0005634^cellular_component^nucleus`GO:0003677^molecular_function^DNA binding`
```

I want to get rid of all of the text related to function and have the output as so:

```
GO:0005634`GO:0003677
```

I'm not sure how to approach this using sed or awk

**Note**: the lines have various amounts of `GO:xxxxxxx`.

Comment: Register your account; then you'll be able to edit your question (and accept answers, and comment on answers, and...)

Answer (score 1):

This does what I believe you're asking for. **NOTE:** `input.txt` is your input file.

*just sed*

```
$ sed 's/\^[^`]*//g' input.txt
GO:0005634`GO:0003677`
GO:0005634`GO:0003677`
GO:0005634`GO:0003677`
GO:0005634`GO:0003677`
```

**Explanation**

`sed` is used to remove the sub-strings that begin with a caret (^) and can contain anything except a single backtick. Once a backtick is encountered, `sed` will replace this with nothing, effectively deleting it. This pattern is repeated until exhausted. This has the effect of removing all the `^....` strings.

*grep + paste + sed*

```
$ grep -o 'GO:[0-9]\+' input.txt | paste -d'`' - - | sed 's/$/`/'
GO:0005634`GO:0003677`
GO:0005634`GO:0003677`
GO:0005634`GO:0003677`
GO:0005634`GO:0003677`
```

**Explanation**

`grep` pulls out all the GO:XXXXX strings from the `input.txt` file, `paste` puts them into 2 columns, with a single tick between the 2 GO:XXXXX strings, and finally the `sed` adds a single tick to the end.

#### References

- [Format output of xargs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89130/format-output-of-xargs/89132#89132)
- [Non greedy (reluctant) regex matching in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-reluctant-regex-matching-in-sed)
- [10 examples of paste command usage in Linux](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/07/10-examples-of-paste-command-usage-in.html)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the data uses backticks as record separators and circumflex as field delimiters.

```
printf 'GO:0005634^cellular_component^nucleus`GO:0003677^molecular_function^DNA binding`' |
awk -F '^' -v RS='`' -v ORS='`' '{ print $1 }'
```

This prints only the first field of each record (the GO term), with backticks as the output record separator.

Output:

```
GO:0005634`GO:0003677`
```

(no trailing newline)

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Awk (`gawk`):

```
gawk 'BEGIN{FPAT="`?GO:[0-9]+"; OFS=""} {$1=$1} 1' file
```

Ex.

```
$ echo 'GO:0005634^cellular_component^nucleus`GO:0003677^molecular_function^DNA binding`' | 
  gawk 'BEGIN{FPAT="`?GO:[0-9]+"; OFS=""} {$1=$1} 1'
GO:0005634`GO:0003677
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'print /((?:^|`)GO:\d+)/g' genes.file
```

***Explanation:***

- Execute `perl` in line mode with explicit printing of records to stdout `-n`
- the regex ***/((?:^|`)GO:\d+)/g*** will, in the current record, the string GO: to whose right is a number and on it's left is either the BOL or a backquote. this is then grabbed as many times as it is found, /g option, and handed over to the print command which then display to stdout with the default OFS which is null.